# Maximum on date field and Views aggregation issue

Tags: views, 8, datetime

I am running a Drupal 8.0.5, I have a content type called show which has fields title, an entity referenced called movie and a date time.
I am trying to create a view of the latest shows of each movie. The initial view is like this which shows the movie and show time

[image: movies and show times]

I enabled aggregation. Aggregation functions i used are For movie - group results together and for datetime - maximum. The result is as follows

[image]

it just gives 2,016 as date time field where i was expecting Mon 03/21/2016 15:00:00. Are we not supposed to aggregate on date field? I thought since MAX usually works in database for timestamp, it is valid here also. Can anything be done to achieve this result?

Comment: I have a similar problem, where the MIN aggregation doesn't filter out any values at all in my view.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, select "None" for "Thousands marker" to have a properly formatted timestamp value;
2. In the "REWRITE RESULTS" section you can override the output of the field.
   Given I have the aggregated field "created" overriding the field would look as following:

   {{ created |timestamp_format('Y-m-d') }}

[image]

Comment: This would be the correct answer if `timestamp_format` would be a Twig filter but it's not. It's called `date`. So you want to write `{{ create | date('Y-m-d') }}` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue should be addressed in the views module.
You can use hook_views_pre_render or (hook_views_post_execute) to modify the values example:

```
YOUR_MODULE_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
    if ($view->id() == 'YOUR_VIEW_ID'){
        $format = "d/m/Y H:i";
        foreach($view->result as $key => $result){
            $result->STRING_FIELD = date($format, result->TIMESTAMP_FIELD);
        }
    }
}
```

WARNING: the destination field must be a string, so you have to add a mock string field to the view (STRING_FIELD).

```
$result->TIMESTAMP_FIELD = date($format, result->TIMESTAMP_FIELD);
```

will not work

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to correct the output of this field (show the full date instead of just the year) seems to be creating a Twig template file for the field, then calling the value directly; you can use twig filters to modify the format as needed.

For example:

- **View**: safety_reports
- **Display**: page_2
- **Date field**: field_safetyrpt_mailing_date
- **Aggregation type**: Maximum
- **Template file name**: views-view-field--safety-reports--page-2--field-safetyrpt-mailing-date.html.twig
- **Template file contents**:

  {{ row.node__field_safetyrpt_mailing_date_field_safetyrpt_mailing_d }}

  or

  {{ row.node__field_safetyrpt_mailing_date_field_safetyrpt_mailing_d | date('F j, Y') }}